# The tanh activation function in backpropagation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, backpropagation

In the backpropagation algorithm when the output activation function is `tanh` and the number of classes is 2 (binary problem), the value obtained at the output layer is in the range between -1 to 1. The cross-entropy error function has `log` that is applied on the predicted values. Therefore, if one of the output values is a negative number, an invalid operation, namely, `log (non-positive number)`, occurs, rendering the cross-entropy function invalid.

This boils down to the following questions:

- Is it disallowed to set the output activation as `tanh`?
- Should the output activation always be the softmax even for a binary class
  problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, The softmax function is used in case of multi class problems and a single logistic function for binary classification. The reason is that the output nonlinearity and the loss "match", that means that the derivative is very simple--a property of generalized linear models.

On a side note, the tanh and the logistic sigmoid are related linearly. Tanh is just the logistic scaled and translated from the $[0, 1]$ to the $[-1, 1]$ interval.

Comment: You are right, however, like I said, the `cross-entropy` cost function, in python syntax, is `cost = -np.sum(Y * np.log(a_output))` (consider the `log`) where `Y` is the real output and `a_output` constitutes the predicted values. Since `tanh` can yield negative values, then `np.log(a_output)` can produce a `math domain error`. This is what is confusing me, the fact that there is a possibility that `log` is applied on negative predicted values, causing a `math error`.

Comment: As bayerj suggests (+1), the tanh is just a rescaling of the logistic sigmoid (which is the normal choice for binary regression).  Just replace a_output with 0.5*(a_output + 1) and this will undo the scaling.  However, there is no good reason to use tanh for binary classification, just use the logistic function instead.  See Bishop's book on Neural Networks for Pattern Recognition for a good discussion of the relationship between cost functions and output layer activation function (and neural nets in general).

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough on this. Thanks to Dikran for compensating that.